# Mysqli simple query: weird result using mysqli_stmt_bind_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a mySQL table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tweet` (
  `user_mail` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_sent` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_edited` datetime NOT NULL,
  `message` tinytext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_mail`,`date_sent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And two differents entries in this table as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `tweet` (`user_mail`, `date_sent`, `date_edited`, `message`) VALUES
('RichardSpencer@gmail.com', '2016-01-22 14:07:45', '', 'First tweet !');

INSERT INTO `tweet` (`user_mail`, `date_sent`, `date_edited`, `message`) VALUES
('JohnDoe@gmail.com', '2016-01-22 14:07:45', '', 'Second tweet  !');
```

I'm using this PHP function to retrieve all tweets (at this moment there are only 2 tweets) of my table 'tweet'

```
function getAllTweets($con, $limit){

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT * FROM tweet ORDER BY date_sent DESC LIMIT 0, ?') or die('Oups erreur dans la requète SELECT avec le message: '.  mysqli_error($con));

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $limit);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $datas['user_mail'], $datas['date_sent'], $datas['date_edited'], $datas['message']);
    while($datas == mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){

        $result []= $datas;
    }

    return $result;    
}
```

And I'm calling this function like this:

```
$allTweets = getAllTweets($con, 99);
```

When I see `var_dump($allTweets);`I get 2 tweets as I was especting but Both results are the same tweet . . . here is the var_dump result

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'user_mail' => string 'johnDoe@gmail.com' (length=17)
      'date_sent' => string '2016-01-22 17:25:34' (length=19)
      'date_edited' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'message' => string 'Second tweet !' (length=14)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'user_mail' => string 'johnDoe@gmail.com' (length=17)
      'date_sent' => string '2016-01-22 17:25:34' (length=19)
      'date_edited' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'message' => string 'Second tweet !' (length=14)
```

If you see my table I should have one tweet with the message "First tweet !"
And a second tweet with a message "Second tweet !"

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: you're binding the results, which internally sets up those variables to be references. you then store those references in your `$result` array, which means every time you fetch another row, ALL of those "previous" results are gone because they're references pointing at whatever the last row you fetched is.

Comment: thank you very much for the help. .Could you give me one or two lines of code I could implement in my function instead of the one I'm using  ?

Comment: don't bind to individual array elements. bind to dedicated variables, then build a new array from those. e.g. `bind($foo, $bar)` -> `$temp = array($foo, $bar)` -> `$data[] = $temp`.

Comment: Thank you very much sir ! I implemented your solution and it works fine now !

I can't vote because I am new user but I promise to come back when I have enought experience to vote for you. Have a nice day.